# Allocation Instruments for iOS: compare memory of two snapshots

Tags: ios, memory-management, xcode-instruments

In my situation I continuously enter one scene, than exit and so on... So `Live bytes` amount must be the same while reentering the scene, but it grows up by 3Mb on each enter.

I want to find memory that remains from previous scene. Memory Leak instrument shows no leaks.
How can I compare two "snapshots" of memory to highlight differences in allocations?

Previous scene snapshot:
[image]

After reentering:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

approach it using Heapshot Analysis

Here's a great blog entry by bbum: [When is a Leak not a Leak? Using Heapshot Analysis to Find Undesirable Memory Growth](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: Thanks! Excellent links. I have met one little difficulty: C++ adresses don't symbolicate (in debug and release builds)...

Comment: Solved it - in Instruments select File->Re-symbolicate Document and locate dSym file for the application.